# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo mediante JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Tengo un diseño y quiero cambiar los estilos desde mi base de datos, estoy aprendiendo ahora y no sé como acomodar el *JavaScript* para que me haga el cambio.

Por ejemplo, tengo en el estilo el color `#e81863` y quiero que sea el que selecciono en la base de datos, por ejemplo, `#e81717`. Este sería el que tengo en la base de datos.

Esta sería la parte del estilo que cambia, aquí esta rosa:

```
/*============= Global ancher link color style ==========*/
a {
    color:#e81863;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:#e81863;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a.invarseColor:link, a.invarseColor:visited {
    color:#666;
}
a.invarseColor:hover, a.invarseColor:active {
    color:#e81863;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.active:link, a.active:visited {
    color:#e81863;
    cursor:default;
}

/*=================== dropdown =============*/
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
    background:#e81863;
    background-color:#e81863;
    filter:#e81863;
}
.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
    background:#e81863;
    background-color:#e81863;
    filter: #e81863;
}

/*==================== navbar =================*/
.navbar .nav > li:hover {
    background:#e81863;
}
/* active link */
.navbar .nav .active a,
.navbar .nav .active a:hover,
.navbar .nav .active a:focus
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > .active > a i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a span,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus span,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover span {
    background: #e81863;
    background-color: #e81863;
    filter:#e81863;
}
/* nested ul */
.navbar .nav div {
    background: #e81863;
}

/*========== btn-primary (orange-btn) ==========*/
.btn-primary {
    border:1px solid #e81863;
    background: #e81863;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e8407f 0%, #e81863 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e8407f), color-stop(100%,#e81863));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e8407f 0%,#e81863 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e8407f 0%,#e81863 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e8407f 0%,#e81863 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8407f 0%,#e81863 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e8407f', endColorstr='#e81863',GradientType=0 );
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled] {
    background: #e81863;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
    background-color: #e8407f;
}
```

Aquí cambia a azul:

```
/*============= Global ancher link color style ==========*/
a {
    color:#0069b4;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:#0069b4;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a.invarseColor:link, a.invarseColor:visited {
    color:#666;
}
a.invarseColor:hover, a.invarseColor:active {
    color:#0069b4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.active:link, a.active:visited {
    color:#0069b4;
    cursor:default;
}

/*=================== dropdown =============*/
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
    background:#0069b4;
    background-color:#0069b4;
    filter:#0069b4;
}
.dropdown-menu .active > a,
.dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
    background:#0069b4;
    background-color:#0069b4;
    filter: #0069b4;
}

/*==================== navbar =================*/
.navbar .nav > li:hover {
    background:#2374b2;
}
/* active link */
.navbar .nav .active a,
.navbar .nav .active a:hover,
.navbar .nav .active a:focus
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > .active > a i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover i,
.navbar .nav > .active > a span,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus span,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover span {
    background: #2374b2;
    background-color: #2374b2;
    filter:#2374b2;
}
/* nested ul */
.navbar .nav div {
    background: #2374b2;
}

/*========== btn-primary (blue-btn) ==========*/
.btn-primary {
    border:1px solid #2374B2;
    background: #2989d8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%, #2374b2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#2374b2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2374b2 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2374b2 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2374b2 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2989d8 0%,#2374b2 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2374b2',GradientType=0 );
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled] {
    background: #2374B2;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active {
    background-color: #2989d8;
}
```

Ahora bien, quiero cambiarlo desde mi base de datos y este es el código que uso para traer el color de la base de datos, lo que no sé es cómo usar los datos de los estilos en el código.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/plantilla.ajax.php",
    success:function(respuesta){
        var Estilocolor = JSON.parse(respuesta).Estilocolor;
        $(".backColor, .backColor a")
            .css({
                "background": Estilocolor,
                "color": colorTexto
            })
        ;
    }
})
```

Este es el ejemplo que tengo y me funciona bien, pero no sé cómo acomodar los estilos que ya tengo en los *CSS* con este *JavaScript*.

Comment: Puedes crear una hoja de estilos utilizando PHP.  Para esto necesitas utilizar un `<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>`al inicio de tu hoja de estilos para decir al navegador que lo que viene a continuación es CSS. Siendo un documento PHP puede recibir un $POST o un $GET cuyo valor puede ser tu color hex. A continuación puedes poner tu CSS, reemplazando el color con una variable PHP. Lea más acerca de [header](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

un consejo , maneja los colores como clases de css eso hara que el tu data se vea mas limpia dejandole la parte fea a css, en tu css podrias adicionar

```
.rojo{
background-color:#ff0000;
}
.azul{
background-color:#0000ff;
}
```

en la base de datos le podrias decir que quieres cambiar el tema de azul a rojo y en tu js podrias poner algo como esto

```
    $.ajax({
            url:"ajax/plantilla.ajax.php",
            success:function(respuesta){
                var data=JSON.parse(respuesta);
                var Estilocolor = data.Estilocolor;
                $(".backColor, .backColor a").addClass(Estilocolor);
            }
        })
```

es mas facil y limpio trabajar con clases y adicionarlas o removerlas de tus objetos que modificar el estilo con .css({}) de jquery.